# toggle button with boolean in UITableView Swift

Tags: swift, core-data, tableview, toggle

I would like to add a boolean toggle to know whether the button has been pressed (will save this value to core data (also would like to save cell data to core data if true and delete from core data if false)) I am not sure how to do this. any help would be greatly appreciated. if all the code from the view controller is required leave a comment and I will do so (I have setup xcdatamodel already).

```
  @IBAction func buttonTapped(_ sender:UIButton) {
    var superView = sender.superview
    while !(superView is UITableViewCell) {
        superView = superView?.superview
    }
    let cell = superView as! UITableViewCell
    if let indexpath = tableView.indexPath(for: cell){

        print(indexpath)
    }
}
```

Comment: where is your button? is it in the cell?

Comment: @taratandel yes the code above is to get the index path of the cell with the button press, would I have to also save the indexpath in the xcdatamodel with a relationship to cell boolean and data?

Comment: So correct me if i'm wrong. you want to press a button which is in the cell and save the data of that cell?

Comment: @taratandel yes and delete if the button is pressed again hence the use of the toggle, default would be false

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well I build a simple project and I figured something out using protocols,
First you define a protocol like this:

```
protocol cellDidRequestSaving {
     func saveOrDelete(indexpath : Int)
}
```

First in your cell you define you button like this :

```
class TableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    var delegate: cellDidRequestSaving?
    var indexPath = 0 //come from the parent
    override func awakeFromNib() {
         super.awakeFromNib()

         // Initialization code
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
         super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

    @IBAction func didTap(_ sender: Any) {
        // this protocol defined in the parent
        delegate?.saveOrDelete(indexpath: indexPath)

    }
}
```

now in you `tableViewController` you use the protocol like this:

```
 class TableViewController: UITableViewController, cellDidRequestSaving {
     var cellStat = [Int:Bool]()
     override func viewDidLoad() {
         super.viewDidLoad()

        // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations
        // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = false

        // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
        // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem
    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source

     override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
         return 1
    }

     override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
         return 3
    }

     override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
         let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell
         cell.indexPath = indexPath.row
         cell.delegate = self
        // Configure the cell...

         return cell
    }
     func saveOrDelete(indexpath: Int) {
         if let status = cellStat[indexpath], status {
            print(indexpath, "delete")
             cellStat[indexpath] = !status
        }
         else {
            print(indexpath, "save")
             cellStat[indexpath] = true
        }
    }
```

This is a simple project but you can get the hole idea about how to do it. Also, notice the protocol definition and usage so you wont miss anything.
and the out put is this [image: Out Put of The Project]

Answer (score 0):

Add a property to your custom cell, for example:

```
var indexPath: IndexPath = IndexPath(row: -1, section: -1)  //The -1 just know when it is not set yet
```

And in `cellForRow` in your tableView:

```
cell.indexpath = indexPath
```

Supposing that `buttonTapped` is defined in your custom cell class:

```
@IBAction func buttonTapped(_ sender:UIButton) {
    print(indexpath)
}
```

Comment: TableViewCell should not know or care about its own IndexPath, ask the tableview for that information.

Answer (score -1):

Add a delegate method to your cell `- (void)myCell:(MyCell *)cell didTapButton:(UIButton *)button`

So then in your VC you can work backwards from the cell object.

```
- (void)myCell:(MyCell *)cell didTapButton:(UIButton *)button
{
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:cell];
    MyObject *object = [self.dataSource objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    // Do something with the knowledge that the button in the cell for the object was tapped... 

    // For example
    object.tapped = YES;
    [object.managedObjectContext save:NULL];
}
```

Just need to convert to swift ;)